# Github svn interface: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to PROPFIND request

Tags: svn, github

I recently moved a project on github and I still use this library in some svn projects as external. However I can't get github svn interface working at this time. If I run

`svn list http://svn.github.com/fabn/zle.git`

I obtain this error

`svn: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to PROPFIND request for '/fabn/zle.git/!svn/bc/0'`

If I run the same command using a fork of my project the list (and also the checkout) goes fine and i obtain what I need (this is the command `svn list http://svn.github.com/JellyBelly/zle.git`)

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue or it's a github problem?

**Update**: I posted a message to github support, and they solved my issue, now both the url are working.

Comment: This is likely a github problem that you should report. I know when they first introduced the svn interface it had similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Moved from comments since this is now solved.*

This is likely a github problem that you should report. I know when they first introduced the svn interface it had similar problems.